# calculate sum of a column after filtering by and grouping on other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I use this code to first filter out my dataframe according to a particular column `role`.

Next, I calculate the sum of the `value` column and add it to the `newColumn`. For now, I get the same value in all rows of the `newCol`. However, now I want to group by the sum per each value of the `id` col. How can I achieve that?

```
    mask = chunk["role"].eq("senior")
    chunk.loc[mask, 'newColumn'] = chunk.loc[mask, 'value'].sum()
```

df

```
id    role      value
1     junior    2
1     senior    3
1     senior    4
2     junior    2
2     senior    6
```

Desired Output:

```
id    role      value     sum
1     junior    2
1     senior    3         7
1     senior    4         7
2     junior    2
2     senior    6         8
2     senior    2         8
```

So I am basically only considering rows where the `role` is `senior`

Comment: could you please provide a sample of you dataframe ? If i were you I would first compute the groupby `id` and then filter by `role` and finally compute the sum

Comment: I added a sample dataset @Netim Makes sense but I am uncertain how to change the existing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try `query` where `role` value is senior then use `groupby.transform`

```py
df['sum'] = (df.query('role == "senior"')
             .groupby('id')['value'].transform('sum'))
```

```
print(df)

   id    role  value  sum
0   1  junior      2  NaN
1   1  senior      3  7.0
2   1  senior      4  7.0
3   2  junior      2  NaN
4   2  senior      6  8.0
5   2  senior      2  8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider adding samples of your dataframe to make it easier for eveyrone to help. Check my sample below - this is what the df structure should be given as when you're asking question.

Something like this should work:

```
# Sample of the data frame
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
       'id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2},
       'role': {0: 'junior', 1: 'senior', 2: 'senior', 3: 'junior', 4: 'senior'},
       'value': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 2, 4: 6}})

# Massaging the data to achieve desired result
>>> print(df
        .merge(df.groupby(['id','role'], as_index=False)[['value']]
        .agg(sum), on=['id','role'])
        .rename({'value_x': 'value', 'value_y': 'sum'}, axis=1))


id  role    value   sum
0   1   junior  2   2
1   1   senior  3   7
2   1   senior  4   7
3   2   junior  2   2
4   2   senior  6   6
```